# como filtrar un string en javascript y agregar solo un grupo de cosas especificas

Tags: javascript, array, string, filtro

Hola estoy haciendo una pagina de contabilidad sacando archivos de una tabla que esta en una pagina la cual obviamente no me pertenece. hasta aquí todo correcto pero soy capas de hacer el proceso copiando solo lo que necesito pero deseo hacer que `JavaScript` me filtre todo y solo tome lo que me interesa.
bueno contexto por medio de un input paso el texto a la función de js pero como dije antes seleccionando lo que me interesa.
paso el código que tengo.

El código `HTML` que funciona muy bien.

```js
function pagina() {
  let creditosPagina = 0;
  creditosPagina = document.getElementById('creditosPagina').value;
  let corte = [];
  corte = creditosPagina.split('    ');
  corte.splice(1, 3);
  let opcion;

  let obj = {};
  obj = Object.assign({
    fecha: corte[0],
    creditos: parseFloat(corte[1])
  })

  let cortes = {
    corte_0: {
      fecha: '27/02/2023 15: 00',
      creditos: 44.35
    },
    corte_1: {
      fecha: null,
      creditos: null
    },
    corte_2: {
      fecha: null,
      creditos: null
    },
    corte_3: {
      fecha: null,
      creditos: null
    },
    corte_4: {
      fecha: null,
      creditos: null
    },
    corte_5: {
      fecha: null,
      creditos: null
    },
    corte_6: {
      fecha: null,
      creditos: null
    },
    corte_7: {
      fecha: null,
      creditos: null
    },
    corte_8: {
      fecha: null,
      creditos: null
    },
    corte_9: {
      fecha: null,
      creditos: null
    }
  };
  if ((cortes.corte_0.fecha === obj.fecha || cortes.corte_0 === null) || (cortes.corte_1.fecha === obj.fecha || cortes.corte_1 === null) || (cortes.corte_2.fecha === obj.fecha || cortes.corte_2 === null) || (cortes.corte_3.fecha === obj.fecha || cortes.corte_3 === null) || (cortes.corte_4.fecha === obj.fecha || cortes.corte_4 === null) || (cortes.corte_5.fecha === obj.fecha || cortes.corte_5 === null) || (cortes.corte_6.fecha === obj.fecha || cortes.corte_6 === null) || (cortes.corte_7.fecha === obj.fecha || cortes.corte_7 === null) || (cortes.corte_8.fecha === obj.fecha || cortes.corte_8 === null) || (cortes.corte_9.fecha === obj.fecha || cortes.corte_9 === null)) {
    alert("corte subido");
  }

  if (cortes.corte_0.fecha === null) {
    cortes.corte_0 = obj;
  } else if (cortes.corte_1.fecha === null) {
    cortes.corte_1 = obj;
  } else if (cortes.corte_2.fecha === null) {
    cortes.corte_2 = obj;
  } else if (cortes.corte_3.fecha === null) {
    cortes.corte_3 = obj;
  } else if (cortes.corte_4.fecha === null) {
    cortes.corte_4 = obj;
  } else if (cortes.corte_5.fecha === null) {
    cortes.corte_5 = obj;
  } else if (cortes.corte_6.fecha === null) {
    cortes.corte_6 = obj;
  } else if (cortes.corte_7.fecha === null) {
    cortes.corte_7 = obj;
  } else if (cortes.corte_8.fecha === null) {
    cortes.corte_8 = obj;
  } else if (cortes.corte_9.fecha === null) {
    cortes.corte_9 = obj;
  } else {
    alert("No Hay Espacio");
  }
  let propiedades = {
    creditosPagina: cortes.corte_0.creditos + cortes.corte_1.creditos + cortes.corte_2.creditos + cortes.corte_3.creditos + cortes.corte_4.creditos + cortes.corte_5.creditos + cortes.corte_6.creditos + cortes.corte_7.creditos + cortes.corte_8.creditos + cortes.corte_9.creditos,
    moneda: window.moneda,
    descuentoPagina: 0.70044843,
    descuentoStudio: 0.8
  }

  propiedades.creditosPagina *= propiedades.descuentoPagina;
  propiedades.creditosPagina *= propiedades.descuentoStudio;
  propiedades.creditosPagina *= propiedades.moneda;


  document.getElementById('resultadoPagina').innerHTML = propiedades.creditosPagina.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById('resultadoPagina2').innerHTML = creditosPagina;
  return cortes;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="Inicio.html">Inicio</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="funcionCreditosTrasmision.html">Creditos Trasmisón</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="funcionCreditosPagina.html">Creditos Pagina</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="funcionCreditosStudio.html">Creditos Studio</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<main>
  <div>
    <h1>Creditos Pagina</h1>

    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing, elit. Neque provident recusandae dolorum. Vero dolorem minus asperiores qui rem, itaque veniam quis praesentium, maiores explicabo nemo nobis aperiam amet, blanditiis accusantium.</p>

    <form id="funcionCreditosPagina" method="get">
      <h3>Creditos Pagina</h3>
      <input type="textoarea" id="creditosPagina">
      <input type="button" value="enviar Creditos" onclick="pagina()">
      <br>
      <div id="resultadoPagina"></div>
      <h2>_____________________________________________________________________</h2>
      <div id="resultadoPagina2"></div>
    </form>
  </div>

</main>

<footer>

</footer>
```

aquí el código de JavaScript que funciona si solo paso un los datos que requiero en la función.
ejemplo:

> 27/02/2023 15:00  Debit   Group Transfer to Cosmo Payment - 000000794 -44.35  0.00

Como les dije antes este código me funciona si solo paso la linia que me interesa
lo que quiero es que si paso este string:

> 02/03/2023 01:09  Debit   DirectCam - Facility Fee Pinnock3838    -0.79   -0.79
> 02/03/2023 01:09    Debit   DirectCam - Advisor Fee Pinnock3838 -0.47   -1.26
> 02/03/2023 01:09    Credit  DirectCam - Pinnock3838 15.70   14.44   Transfer Requested on 03/03/2023
> 02/03/2023 22:21    Debit   DirectCam - Facility Fee only_you   -0.00   14.44
> 02/03/2023 22:21    Debit   DirectCam - Advisor Fee only_you    -0.00   14.44
> 02/03/2023 22:21    Credit  DirectCam - only_you    0.02    14.46   Transfer Requested on 04/03/2023
> 02/03/2023 23:25    Debit   DirectCam - Facility Fee jimjam1231993  -0.09   14.38
> 02/03/2023 23:25    Debit   DirectCam - Advisor Fee jimjam1231993   -0.05   14.32
> 02/03/2023 23:25    Credit  DirectCam - jimjam1231993   1.73    16.05   Transfer Requested on 04/03/2023
> 02/03/2023 23:56    Debit   DirectCam - Facility Fee Markkos111 -0.60   15.45
> 02/03/2023 23:56    Debit   DirectCam - Advisor Fee Markkos111  -0.36   15.09
> 02/03/2023 23:56    Credit  DirectCam - Markkos111  12.03   27.12   Transfer Requested on 04/03/2023
> 03/03/2023 00:51    Debit   DirectCam - Facility Fee Amc1978    -0.04   27.08
> 03/03/2023 00:51    Debit   DirectCam - Advisor Fee Amc1978 -0.03   27.05
> 03/03/2023 00:51    Credit  DirectCam - Amc1978 0.88    27.93   Transfer Requested on 04/03/2023
> 03/03/2023 01:39    Debit   DirectCam - Facility Fee Groggyfella    -0.03   27.90
> 03/03/2023 01:39    Debit   DirectCam - Advisor Fee Groggyfella -0.02   27.88
> 03/03/2023 01:39    Credit  DirectCam - Groggyfella 0.62    28.50   Transfer Requested on 04/03/2023
> 03/03/2023 15:02    Debit   Group Transfer to Cosmo Payment - 000000794 -15.70  12.80
> 04/03/2023 01:39    Debit   DirectCam - Facility Fee d0rrans    -0.34   12.46
> 04/03/2023 01:39    Debit   DirectCam - Advisor Fee d0rrans -0.20   12.26
> 04/03/2023 01:39    Credit  DirectCam - d0rrans 6.80    19.06   Available for Transfer Now
> 04/03/2023 01:44    Debit   DirectCam - Facility Fee d0rrans    -0.06   19.00
> 04/03/2023 01:44    Debit   DirectCam - Advisor Fee d0rrans -0.03   18.97
> 04/03/2023 01:44    Credit  DirectCam - d0rrans 1.12    20.09   Available for Transfer Now
> 04/03/2023 01:45    Debit   DirectCam - Facility Fee LondonLiving   -0.01   20.08
> 04/03/2023 01:45    Debit   DirectCam - Advisor Fee LondonLiving    -0.01   20.07
> 04/03/2023 01:45    Credit  DirectCam - LondonLiving    0.17    20.24   Available for Transfer Now
> 04/03/2023 01:46    Debit   DirectCam - Facility Fee The_Guy_   -0.22   20.03
> 04/03/2023 01:46    Debit   DirectCam - Advisor Fee The_Guy_    -0.13   19.90
> 04/03/2023 01:46    Credit  DirectCam - The_Guy_    4.31    24.21   Available for Transfer Now
> 04/03/2023 01:46    Debit   DirectCam - Facility Fee d0rrans    -0.02   24.19
> 04/03/2023 01:46    Debit   DirectCam - Advisor Fee d0rrans -0.01   24.18
> 04/03/2023 01:46    Credit  DirectCam - d0rrans 0.32    24.50   Available for Transfer Now
> 04/03/2023 01:53    Debit   DirectCam - Facility Fee The_Guy_   -0.36   24.14
> 04/03/2023 01:53    Debit   DirectCam - Advisor Fee The_Guy_    -0.22   23.92
> 04/03/2023 01:53    Credit  DirectCam - The_Guy_    7.27    31.19   Available for Transfer Now
> 04/03/2023 01:57    Credit  DirectCam tip from d0rrans (0607271677894884)   5.00    36.19   Available for Transfer Now
> 04/03/2023 02:01    Credit  DirectCam tip from d0rrans (0607271677894884)   5.00    41.19   Available for Transfer Now
> 04/03/2023 02:02    Debit   DirectCam - Facility Fee d0rrans    -0.55   40.64
> 04/03/2023 02:02    Debit   DirectCam - Advisor Fee d0rrans -0.33   40.31
> 04/03/2023 02:02    Credit  DirectCam - d0rrans 10.97   51.28   Available for Transfer Now
> 04/03/2023 15:13    Debit   Group Transfer to Cosmo Payment - 000000794 -15.28  36.00
> 04/03/2023 20:21    Debit   DirectCam - Facility Fee KnightManc -0.00   36.00
> 04/03/2023 20:21    Debit   DirectCam - Advisor Fee KnightManc  -0.00   36.00
> 04/03/2023 20:21    Credit  DirectCam - KnightManc  0.02    36.02   Available for Transfer on 05/03/2023 at 20:21
> 04/03/2023 22:24    Debit   DirectCam - Facility Fee shimmy2121 -0.15   35.87
> 04/03/2023 22:24    Debit   DirectCam - Advisor Fee shimmy2121  -0.09   35.79
> 04/03/2023 22:24    Credit  DirectCam - shimmy2121  2.97    38.76   Available for Transfer on 05/03/2023 at 22:24
> 04/03/2023 23:25    Debit   DirectCam - Facility Fee burb25 -0.25   38.51
> 04/03/2023 23:25    Debit   DirectCam - Advisor Fee burb25  -0.15   38.36
> 04/03/2023 23:25    Credit  DirectCam - burb25  4.95    43.31   Available for Transfer on 05/03/2023 at 23:25
> 05/03/2023 00:32    Debit   DirectCam - Facility Fee The_Guy_   -0.55   42.76
> 05/03/2023 00:32    Debit   DirectCam - Advisor Fee The_Guy_    -0.33   42.44
> 05/03/2023 00:32    Credit  DirectCam - The_Guy_    10.92   53.36   Available for Transfer on 06/03/2023 at 00:32
> 05/03/2023 00:39    Debit   DirectCam - Facility Fee A1UKGuy67  -0.01   53.34
> 05/03/2023 00:39    Debit   DirectCam - Advisor Fee A1UKGuy67   -0.01   53.33
> 05/03/2023 00:39    Credit  DirectCam - A1UKGuy67   0.29    53.62   Available for Transfer on 06/03/2023 at 00:39
> 05/03/2023 00:40    Debit   DirectCam - Facility Fee rattleking1    -0.46   53.16
> 05/03/2023 00:40    Debit   DirectCam - Advisor Fee rattleking1 -0.28   52.89
> 05/03/2023 00:40    Credit  DirectCam - rattleking1 9.18    62.07   Available for Transfer on 06/03/2023 at 00:40
> 05/03/2023 00:42    Debit   DirectCam - Facility Fee DavND  -0.01   62.05
> 05/03/2023 00:42    Debit   DirectCam - Advisor Fee DavND   -0.01   62.05
> 05/03/2023 00:42    Credit  DirectCam - DavND   0.27    62.32   Available for Transfer on 06/03/2023 at 00:42
> 05/03/2023 03:03    Debit   DirectCam - Facility Fee WFCY__00   -0.01   62.30
> 05/03/2023 03:03    Debit   DirectCam - Advisor Fee WFCY__00    -0.01   62.29
> 05/03/2023 03:03    Credit  DirectCam - WFCY__00    0.29    62.58   Available for Transfer on 06/03/2023 at 03:03

que la funcion me filtre todo eso y me saque solo lo que me interesa que seria esto

> 03/03/2023 15:02  Debit   Group Transfer to Cosmo Payment - 000000794 -15.70  12.80
> 04/03/2023 15:13    Debit   Group Transfer to Cosmo Payment - 000000794 -15.28  36.00

de todo eso solo serian esas dos líneas.

También necesito que al hacer ese filtro y vaya a agregar los datos de fecha y hora en el objeto haga una verificación.

- primero si esos datos ya fueron subidos y mandar la alerta
- segundo que mire en el objeto cual es el siguiente objeto vacío y ponerlo hay si no ha sido subida esa información.

Soy nuevo usando JavaScript por eso verán que tal vez uso código largo que podría simplificar mas si me pueden ayudar con eso les agradezco seria de mucha ayuda.

Es un proyecto personal no estoy ganando dinero con ese proyecto lo emprendí para aprender mas sobre como crear mi propia pagina  web les agradezco desde ya la atención prestada a este servidor y la ayuda prestada si de pronto necesitan mas detalles o alguna duda la pueden dejar en los comentarios y les responderé.

Muchas gracias a todos

Comment: Yo no entendí el problema. El string de entrada es ese lago ¿Verdad?, supongo que cloada registro está separado por un salto de línea? Luego, la salida esperada es un filtro a esos registros (en tu ejemplo sería los 2 últimos), pero que criterio debe cumplir un registro para ser seleccionado??

Comment: si ese es el string desde un input Group Transfer to Cosmo Payment - 000000794 ese es el criterio principal que es el envio de las ganancia a la cuenta bancaria el resto de datos es la ganancia  pues para saber cuanto va ser enviado a fin de quincena.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar una expresión regular como esta: `.*Group Transfer to Cosmo Payment - 000000794.*$` que busca todas las líneas que contengan la frase `Group Transfer to Cosmo Payment - 000000794`

Ejemplo

```js
const busqueda = "Group Transfer to Cosmo Payment - 000000794";
const regex = new RegExp(`.*${busqueda}.*$`,"gm");
const texto = textarea.value;

const resultados = texto.match(regex);

console.log(resultados);
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea">
02/03/2023 01:09 Debit DirectCam - Facility Fee Pinnock3838 -0.79 -0.79
02/03/2023 01:09 Debit DirectCam - Advisor Fee Pinnock3838 -0.47 -1.26
02/03/2023 01:09 Credit DirectCam - Pinnock3838 15.70 14.44 Transfer Requested on 03/03/2023 02/03/2023 22:21 Debit DirectCam - Facility Fee only_you -0.00 14.44
02/03/2023 22:21 Debit DirectCam - Advisor Fee only_you -0.00 14.44
02/03/2023 22:21 Credit DirectCam - only_you 0.02 14.46 Transfer Requested on 04/03/2023 02/03/2023 23:25 Debit DirectCam - Facility Fee jimjam1231993 -0.09 14.38
02/03/2023 23:25 Debit DirectCam - Advisor Fee jimjam1231993 -0.05 14.32
02/03/2023 23:25 Credit DirectCam - jimjam1231993 1.73 16.05 Transfer Requested on 04/03/2023 02/03/2023 23:56 Debit DirectCam - Facility Fee Markkos111 -0.60 15.45
02/03/2023 23:56 Debit DirectCam - Advisor Fee Markkos111 -0.36 15.09
02/03/2023 23:56 Credit DirectCam - Markkos111 12.03 27.12 Transfer Requested on 04/03/2023 03/03/2023 00:51 Debit DirectCam - Facility Fee Amc1978 -0.04 27.08
03/03/2023 00:51 Debit DirectCam - Advisor Fee Amc1978 -0.03 27.05
03/03/2023 00:51 Credit DirectCam - Amc1978 0.88 27.93 Transfer Requested on 04/03/2023 03/03/2023 01:39 Debit DirectCam - Facility Fee Groggyfella -0.03 27.90
03/03/2023 01:39 Debit DirectCam - Advisor Fee Groggyfella -0.02 27.88
03/03/2023 01:39 Credit DirectCam - Groggyfella 0.62 28.50 Transfer Requested on 04/03/2023
03/03/2023 15:02 Debit Group Transfer to Cosmo Payment - 000000794 -15.70 12.80
04/03/2023 01:39 Debit DirectCam - Facility Fee d0rrans -0.34 12.46
04/03/2023 01:39 Debit DirectCam - Advisor Fee d0rrans -0.20 12.26
04/03/2023 01:39 Credit DirectCam - d0rrans 6.80 19.06 Available for Transfer Now 04/03/2023 01:44 Debit DirectCam - Facility Fee d0rrans -0.06 19.00
04/03/2023 01:44 Debit DirectCam - Advisor Fee d0rrans -0.03 18.97
04/03/2023 01:44 Credit DirectCam - d0rrans 1.12 20.09 Available for Transfer Now 04/03/2023 01:45 Debit DirectCam - Facility Fee LondonLiving -0.01 20.08
04/03/2023 01:45 Debit DirectCam - Advisor Fee LondonLiving -0.01 20.07
04/03/2023 01:45 Credit DirectCam - LondonLiving 0.17 20.24 Available for Transfer Now 04/03/2023 01:46 Debit DirectCam - Facility Fee The_Guy_ -0.22 20.03
04/03/2023 01:46 Debit DirectCam - Advisor Fee The_Guy_ -0.13 19.90
04/03/2023 01:46 Credit DirectCam - The_Guy_ 4.31 24.21 Available for Transfer Now 04/03/2023 01:46 Debit DirectCam - Facility Fee d0rrans -0.02 24.19
04/03/2023 01:46 Debit DirectCam - Advisor Fee d0rrans -0.01 24.18
04/03/2023 01:46 Credit DirectCam - d0rrans 0.32 24.50 Available for Transfer Now 04/03/2023 01:53 Debit DirectCam - Facility Fee The_Guy_ -0.36 24.14
04/03/2023 01:53 Debit DirectCam - Advisor Fee The_Guy_ -0.22 23.92
04/03/2023 01:53 Credit DirectCam - The_Guy_ 7.27 31.19 Available for Transfer Now 04/03/2023 01:57 Credit DirectCam tip from d0rrans (0607271677894884) 5.00 36.19 Available for Transfer Now 04/03/2023 02:01 Credit DirectCam tip from d0rrans (0607271677894884) 5.00 41.19 Available for Transfer Now 04/03/2023 02:02 Debit DirectCam - Facility Fee d0rrans -0.55 40.64
04/03/2023 02:02 Debit DirectCam - Advisor Fee d0rrans -0.33 40.31
04/03/2023 02:02 Credit DirectCam - d0rrans 10.97 51.28 Available for Transfer Now 04/03/2023 15:13 Debit Group Transfer to Cosmo Payment - 000000794 -15.28 36.00
04/03/2023 20:21 Debit DirectCam - Facility Fee KnightManc -0.00 36.00
04/03/2023 20:21 Debit DirectCam - Advisor Fee KnightManc -0.00 36.00
04/03/2023 20:21 Credit DirectCam - KnightManc 0.02 36.02 Available for Transfer on 05/03/2023 at 20:21 04/03/2023 22:24 Debit DirectCam - Facility Fee shimmy2121 -0.15 35.87
04/03/2023 22:24 Debit DirectCam - Advisor Fee shimmy2121 -0.09 35.79
04/03/2023 22:24 Credit DirectCam - shimmy2121 2.97 38.76 Available for Transfer on 05/03/2023 at 22:24 04/03/2023 23:25 Debit DirectCam - Facility Fee burb25 -0.25 38.51
04/03/2023 23:25 Debit DirectCam - Advisor Fee burb25 -0.15 38.36
04/03/2023 23:25 Credit DirectCam - burb25 4.95 43.31 Available for Transfer on 05/03/2023 at 23:25 05/03/2023 00:32 Debit DirectCam - Facility Fee The_Guy_ -0.55 42.76
05/03/2023 00:32 Debit DirectCam - Advisor Fee The_Guy_ -0.33 42.44
05/03/2023 00:32 Credit DirectCam - The_Guy_ 10.92 53.36 Available for Transfer on 06/03/2023 at 00:32 05/03/2023 00:39 Debit DirectCam - Facility Fee A1UKGuy67 -0.01 53.34
05/03/2023 00:39 Debit DirectCam - Advisor Fee A1UKGuy67 -0.01 53.33
05/03/2023 00:39 Credit DirectCam - A1UKGuy67 0.29 53.62 Available for Transfer on 06/03/2023 at 00:39 05/03/2023 00:40 Debit DirectCam - Facility Fee rattleking1 -0.46 53.16
05/03/2023 00:40 Debit DirectCam - Advisor Fee rattleking1 -0.28 52.89
05/03/2023 00:40 Credit DirectCam - rattleking1 9.18 62.07 Available for Transfer on 06/03/2023 at 00:40 05/03/2023 00:42 Debit DirectCam - Facility Fee DavND -0.01 62.05
05/03/2023 00:42 Debit DirectCam - Advisor Fee DavND -0.01 62.05
05/03/2023 00:42 Credit DirectCam - DavND 0.27 62.32 Available for Transfer on 06/03/2023 at 00:42 05/03/2023 03:03 Debit DirectCam - Facility Fee WFCY__00 -0.01 62.30
05/03/2023 03:03 Debit DirectCam - Advisor Fee WFCY__00 -0.01 62.29
05/03/2023 03:03 Credit DirectCam - WFCY__00 0.29 62.58 Available for Transfer on 06/03/2023 at 03:03
03/03/2023 15:02 Debit Group Transfer to Cosmo Payment - 000000794 -15.70 12.80
04/03/2023 15:13 Debit Group Transfer to Cosmo Payment - 000000794 -15.28 36.00
</textarea>
```

Comment: muchas gracias me funciono muy bien